# MySQL Repository for EA through C# Addins

Tags: c#, mysql, enterprise-architect

We have implemented import/export functionality for XML in Enterprise architect.

Our .EAP file is exceeding 1Gb, we are not able to work efficiently with MS Access. Also facing a huge performance issue while importing XML to EA.

Thus, we are planning to move to MySQL.

Is there any document to setup up the repository through C# Addin.

Can we directly save the model to My SQL as we have the whole import code for MS Access?

How easy will it be to move to My SQL Repository?

Can we import XML to My SQL repository using any EA API without having to access each and every table created?? 
Because we don’t know the internal table structure.

Answer (score 1):

You simple setup the MySQL server like [described by Sparx](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/8.0/projects_and_teams/createanewmysqlrepository.html). Once done, you transfer your existing EAP based repository to the new MySQL DB with `Project/Data Management/Project Transfer`. This will make a 1:1 copy and you can instantly switch to the new DB.